# Are there any differences between preparing/cooking a turkey that was labeled "basted with real butter" vs a regular turkey?

Tags: roasting, turkey, brining

I've roasted numerous turkeys numerous ways, but never bought a turkey that was basted with butter. I've always just bought a regular turkey, usually I brine it, and then roast it. I've always had great results. As I've never thought to buy one, I've never given it any thought.

I got this turkey for free and am wondering any considerations I need to account for with this pre-basted turkey? What would happen if I brined it?

Edit:
Here's the actual product: 
http://www.presidentschoice.ca/en_CA/products/productlisting/pc_young_turkey_basted_with_real_butter19732.html

[image]

Comment: Regarding the possibility of brining, see [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10438/15018).  The main question is whether the "pre-basted" also includes a salt solution injection.  Most commercial pre-basted birds do.  The ingredients list should give you some hints about what was added.

Comment: You can't serve it to someone who's keeping Kosher?  (because you're mixing meat & dairy.  But they'd have to not so strict that they wouldn't eat food from a kitchen that hasn't been blessed)

Comment: Whenever I see ad copy that blares "blah blah blah REAL BUTTER", the question that comes to mind is "as opposed to imaginary butter?" :p

Answer (score 1):

Chances are most likely that it will be just fine. I suspect the brine process will "wash away" a lot of the butter stuff. I've worked in a meat shop before and the only concern I've ever heard expressed about them is dairy allergy, so do keep that in mind. Otherwise, I would (and have) just cook them as you are used to.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a big no-no, but it's a small no-no. Brining is not likely to make your turkey much more flavorful (at least not in a positive way), because it has most likely already been brined. We can be sure if you post label info. Additional brining is likely to make it over salty. Butterball brand is of this type, brining will do nothing but make it saltier.

That's not to say that pre-brined turkeys are equivalent to fresh turkeys you brine yourself. They aren't. The best birds are purchased untreated, and brined within a couple of days of cooking.

Comment: That's mostly what I thought. I got this turkey for free, so I'm trying to figure out what's the best solution for it.

Comment: @talon8 I'd say spatchcock it and baste it several times in the last hour with butter mixed with flavorings you like and a bit of chicken base (like better than bouillon, preferably reduced sodium.) It appears (from the reviews) that it's already brined by injection, so I wouldn't brine it.